# How to reload page when select box selected

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu

I want to reload the page when the option is selected. The form is used to select and delete all selected.

My code:

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementById("sort_filter").submit();
}
```

```html
<form action="action/delete.php" id="select_delete_form" method="get">

  <div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#check-all" class="btn btn-primary" id="check-all">Select All</a>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete Selected" onclick="return deleletconfig()">
  </div>

  <select id="sort_filter" name="sort_filter" method="get" onchange="change()">
    <optgroup label="Sort by">
      <option value="new">Newest</option>
      <option value="old">Oldest</option>
      <option value="most">Most Popular</option>
      <option value="less">Less Popular</option>
      <option value="user">Owner</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

  <input type="checkbox" value="11111" name="deleteid[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="22222" name="deleteid[]">

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call submit on the [form element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) not the select element

```
function change(){
    document.getElementById("select_delete_form").submit();
}
```

If submiting isn't what you are looking for, then maybe a form reset would be better?

```
function change(){
    document.getElementById("select_delete_form").reset();
}
```

If you truly want to reload the page, then:

```
function change(){
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: if i do it, the page will reload to acton/delete.php. i cant create form in form. so theres no another way unless using form?

Comment: why do you want to reload the page? Couldn't you just do a form reset? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Comment: hmm, when i select for example "newest" so the page will select another database and order it by `date DESC`.